# Why can std::map::emplace usage leak memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

In a recent [article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/11/overview-of-std-map-insertion-emplacement-methods-in-cpp17/) I read that the following use of std::map::emplace might leak memory, but I do not see why:

```
// might leak if allocation fails due to insufficient memory for an object A
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<A>> m;
m.emplace(1, std::make_unique<A>("Ann",63));
```

Can anybody explain?

Comment: I think author needs to explain this questionable statement

Comment: Yeah... that is just not true.

Comment: As a reminder, you don't need to tag the various versions if you aren't asking the particularities about them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The snippet you've posted will not cause a memory leak if say the allocation of a new node by the `map` fails due to low memory. You've constructed a `unique_ptr` before calling `map::emplace`, so if that function throws, the `unique_ptr` will `delete A` and avoid a leak.

What the author presumably means is the following code will leak memory under similar conditions

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<A>> m;
m.emplace(1, new A("Ann",63));
```

In this case you're passing a raw pointer to `emplace` and relying on the function to transfer ownership of the pointer to a `unique_ptr`. If the function throws during the allocation of a new node, no `unique_ptr` would've been constructed to take ownership of the pointer and the memory will be leaked.

Comment: Things like this of course are one of the reasons why `make_unique` *exists*.